# Modsecurity waf in nginx server

Tags: nginx, mod-security, web-application-firewall

I am struggling with mod-security WAF in nginx setup any explain what is mod-security and how to implement in nginx. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the official guide from NGINX - https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-and-installing-modsecurity-for-open-source-nginx/

Here is a guide for Ubuntu - https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-and-enable-modsecurity-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-server/

Here is a guide for CentOS - https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-modsecurity-for-nginx-on-centos-7-debian-8-and-ubuntu-16-04

If you do not know what the library MOD_SECURITY is used for - [the official About page](https://www.modsecurity.org/about.html)